# How use controller ListView Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, listview

I want to print a message when I'm at the end of listView.

I have 2 listview, one inside the other.

that's my code in stateful widget:

```
class _CategoryScreenState extends State<CategoryScreen> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  scrollController.addListener(() {
      if(scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent){
        print('At the end');
      }
    });
  }
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      key: widget._scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(....),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  itemCount: myProvider.myArray.length,
                  controller: scrollController,

                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (_,index){
                    return MyWidget(
                      dishModel: myProvider.myArray[index],
                    );
                  }),
           
            ],

          )),
    );
  }
}
```

When I scroll to the end of list, nothing happend.

How I can solve??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your init do this instead

```
scrollController = new ScrollController(initialScrollOffset:5.0)..addListener(() {
      if(scrollController.offset >= scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !scrollController.position.outofRange){
        print('At the end');
      }
    });

``
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the outer ListView into NestedScrollView. It takes a constructor argument named `controller` which is ScrollController.